# Jquery - How list id elements contained from a div

Tags: jquery

If I have a div like this:

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="but" id="1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="but" id="2">Text 2</div>
</div>
```

How can I create an array of all IDs of the `.but` elements contained in  the `#box` div?

In the example will be `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var ids = $('#box > .but').map(function() {
    return this.id || null;
}).get();
```

This will create an entry for every `.but` child of the `#box` element **iff** it has an ID (`null` values are discarded, if an element has no ID, `this.id` will return an empty string (which evaluates to `false`)). If every element has definitely an ID or you don't care/want potentially empty values in the array, you can omit the `|| null` part.

If you want to get the ID of every `.but` descendant, change the selector to:

```
$('#box .but')
```

**Reference**: [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: This will push id's that don't have the `.but` class.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var idArray = new Array();
$('#box .but').each(function() {
    idArray.push(this.id);
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/bLYEQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .each to loop through all elements in a result set:

```
var ar=[]
$('div.but').each(function(){
    ar.push(this.id);
});
```

### Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/v7gWM/).

Comment: This will create empty entries if an element has no ID. But it might be sufficient... depends on the actual use case.

Comment: Outside the scope of the question.

Comment: This will include elements with the class but that aren't inside of the #box div.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var ar = jQuery('div#box').children('.but').map( function() {
    return jQuery(this).attr('id');
}).get();
alert(ar);
```

**@flexi kling** thanks for the information of beautiful functions `map` and `get`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uCeZu/1)

Comment: @Flexi Kling Thanks for the `get`

Comment: You're welcome :D But it makes me think why you created this answer at all as it is basically the same as mine ;) (apart from that you select *all* children and not only the `.but` elements)...

Comment: @Flexi oops! i forget to write `.but` inside `children`..now updated

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var idArray = new Array();

$(".but").each(function(index, item) { idArray.push(item.id); });
```